# How to fetch only first rows group from ordered dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset

```
| id | field1 | field2 |
|----|--------|--------|
| 1  | 1      | a      |
| 2  | 2      | b      |
| 3  | 1      | c      |
| 4  | 2      | d      |
```

I want to order this dataset by *field1* and fetch only first group with single query.

Specifically:

```
| id | field1 | field2 |
|----|--------|--------|
| 1  | 1      | a      |
| 3  | 1      | c      |
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it

```
SELECT id, field1, field2
  FROM table1
 WHERE field1 = (
   SELECT MIN(field1)
     FROM table1
 )
 ORDER BY id, field2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0a1da/2)

Result:

```
| id | field1 | field2 |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 |      1 |      a |
|  3 |      1 |      c |
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this. Select values which have no `field1` value in the table less than that row:

```
SELECT *
FROM data d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM data d2
                  WHERE d2.field1 < d1.field1);
```

Self join the table on `field1` and select only rows which have no matching rows with a lower `field1` value:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM data d1
LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d2.field1 < d1.field1
WHERE d2.id IS NULL;
```

Find the `MIN(field1)` value and select rows with `field1` equal to that:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE field1 = (SELECT MIN(field1) 
                FROM data);
```

In all cases the output is

```
id  field1  field2
1   1       a
3   1       c
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ga1yJpVpYGucVopAQCA4QJ/0)